# How to remove space between bannner and content in wordpress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with some CSS ,maybe someone can help me out .

I dont see any margin or padding there that will be the problem.Only that the height is to big or something.

I am using wordpress Sydney theme.

This is the [website](http://dev.springforce.co/dd/services/).

How can i get the space out between the banner and the content of the page ?
Here is a screenshot of what i mean.

[image: screenshot]

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230 px;
    z - index: 999;
    width: 1170 px;
    margin - left: auto;
    margin - right: auto;
}
```

you only have to do this..

```
Position : absolute
```

Will work ☺

Comment: If this answer satisfy which answer you want then mark as a perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

There is one element (#sf-slider-overlay) with wrong position.

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
    position: relative;
    top: 230px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 1170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Change it to,

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 1170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So Simple just add below code to custom css style of your theme

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Your problem will be solved or put above code in your page css.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the space isn't caused by any margin or padding. The space is caused by an element that has been moved out of the way using position relative.

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  width: 1170px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

If you change this to have a `position:absolute;` it fixes the extra space that you had.

Like this:

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  width: 1170px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

You may have to fiddle with the positioning slightly to get it right, I noticed that once `absolute` has been set, the word "Domestic" sits right on the edge of the screen, so perhaps add a `left:2em;` to the property, or even `padding-left:2em;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `position: relative;` in the element `#sf-slider-overlay`. `position: relative;` takes an element out of the float, but the space remains there.

You can use `position: absolute;` but have to set the `left` property to get the same result as now:

```
#sf-slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    translate: translateX(-50%);
}
```